# amplify configure Error: can't find module

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Following https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/react-native/#option-2-follow-the-instructions

I did:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

Then followed with:

```
amplify configure
```

I have Node.js, git, and npm all installed with versions that should be compatible.

After doing amplify configure:

I receive the following error:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ @aws-amplify\cli\lib\run.js'
> ←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)←[39m ←[90m    at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)←[39m
> ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m ←[90m    at
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {   code:
> ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,   requireStack: [] }

I'm on Windows 10

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Edit:
Also just another note. When I try to reinstall the -g @aws-amplify/cli it says it is already installed:
Here are the first two lines:

> npm ERR! code EEXIST

> npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ @aws-amplify\cli\lib\run.js

So, the paths appear to be the same.

Edit:

Although when I do cd @aws-amplify it returns:
The system cannot find the path specified.

this is after I am already successfully in the node_modules folder

And navigating into the npm folder there are three things labeled amplify. A file, Windows Command Script, and Windows PowerShell.
So has the installation process changed. Now that I've located these files how is AWS Amplify CLI supposed to work so I can set up with amplify configure

Solution:

I put this in one of the comments below but figured people may want to try this in the future if they come across the same error.

"I eventually fixed it by first editing the PATH in my system and then doing a --force reinstall of the files. My guess is something went wrong during the initial installation because it worked after I overwrote the previous files, and I noticed some of the files were missing before I did it. Not sure why it didn't work during my initial installation though."

Answer (score 2):

I hope it's not too late. Have you tried:

```
npm install aws-amplify
```

Regards

Comment: Yeah, I did. But I eventually fixed it by first editing the PATH in my system and then doing a --force reinstall of the files. My guess is something went wrong during the initial installation because it worked after I overwrote the previous files, and I noticed some of the files were missing before I did it. Not sure why it didn't work during my initial installation though. Thanks anyway!